# How to populate DataTable correctly using OLeDB Queries

Tags: c#, datatable

***Edit 2 Please Read***: This is a **Very** specific question, since the code runs fine, it just doesn't work the way I'd have hoped. Please read through and be sure you understand where I need help before posting an answer or comment. Much appreciated.

I'm a novice programmer/coder. I'm trying to populate a **DataTable** with details of an selected Employee's Holiday from a **Access Database Table** of all Employee's Holidays. At the moment, using queries, my code counts how many Holidays are in the Database's [Holiday] Table that have the PayrollNo of the selected Employee. From there it populates new lines in the **DataTable** in the program with the **first Holiday with the associated PayrollNo** by the amount of Holidays the employee has take.

For example: Ben has **3 holidays**, but the table will populate his **first** Holiday on **3** lines.

This shows the program counts his holidays correctly but I've done something wrong regarding selecting each individual holiday of an employee.

It also shows its being written to the table in the format I desired.

What I want to be able to do seems quite simple; to have the table populated with all 3 of Ben's Holidays, not just his first.

Below is the section of my code where it iterates a loop for the number of holidays the selected employee has in `[Holiday]`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); //Creates Table
dt.Clear();

dt.Columns.Add("Hol/Abs", typeof(string));      // Column 0  
dt.Columns.Add("FirstDay", typeof(DateTime));   // Column 1 
dt.Columns.Add("LastDay", typeof(DateTime));    // Column 2
dt.Columns.Add("TotalDays", typeof(int));       // Column 3
dt.Columns.Add("Reason", typeof(string));       // Column 4

LblName.Text = PassName; //Loads Name

string ConnString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\HoliPlanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";

string Query = "SELECT PayrollNo FROM [Employee] WHERE (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) = @Name"; //Will supply selected Employee's PayrollNo

string CountHolQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo"; //Will count all of that Employee's Holidays
string CountAbsQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Absences] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo"; //Will count all of that Employee's Absences
string GetStartQuery = "SELECT StartDate FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo"; // Will select the start date of Holidays
string GetEndQuery = "SELECT EndDate FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo"; // Will select the start date of Absences
string GetReasonQuery = "SELECT Reason FROM [Holiday] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo";
string AbsGetStartQuery = "SELECT StartDate FROM [Absences] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo";
string AbsGetEndQuery = "SELECT EndDate FROM [Absences] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo";
string AbsGetReasonQuery = "SELECT Comments FROM [Absences] WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo";

using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
using (OleDbCommand GetPayroll = new OleDbCommand(Query, conn))            
{
    conn.Open();                
    GetPayroll.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = LblName.Text;
    int GotPayroll = Convert.ToInt32(GetPayroll.ExecuteScalar());   //Uses Query to Get PayrollNo
    OleDbCommand CountRowsInHol = new OleDbCommand(CountHolQuery, conn);
    OleDbCommand CountRowsInAbs = new OleDbCommand(CountAbsQuery, conn);
    CountRowsInHol.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GotPayroll;
    CountRowsInAbs.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GotPayroll;
    int HolidayCount = (int) (CountRowsInHol.ExecuteScalar()); //Uses CountHolQuery to Get HowMany lines are in [Holiday] 
    int AbsenceCount = (int)(CountRowsInAbs.ExecuteScalar()); //Uses CountAbsQuery to Get HowMany lines are in [Absences] 
    int HolLoopCount = 1;

    while (HolLoopCount <= HolidayCount) //Will go though all SelectedPayroll's holidays' in [Holiday]
    {                                        
        OleDbCommand GetStart = new OleDbCommand(GetStartQuery, conn);
        OleDbCommand GetEnd = new OleDbCommand(GetEndQuery, conn);
        OleDbCommand GetReason = new OleDbCommand(GetReasonQuery, conn);
        GetStart.Parameters.Add("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GotPayroll;                    
        GetEnd.Parameters.Add("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GotPayroll;
        GetReason.Parameters.Add("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.Integer).Value = GotPayroll;
        DateTime StartHold = Convert.ToDateTime(GetStart.ExecuteScalar());
        DateTime EndHold = Convert.ToDateTime(GetEnd.ExecuteScalar());
        string ReasonHold = (GetReason.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
        DataRow NewLine = dt.NewRow();
        NewLine["Hol/Abs"] = "Holiday";
        NewLine["FirstDay"] = StartHold;
        NewLine["LastDay"] = EndHold;
        NewLine["TotalDays"] = GetNoWeekends(StartHold,EndHold);
        NewLine["Reason"] = ReasonHold;
        dt.Rows.Add(NewLine);
        HolLoopCount = HolLoopCount + 1;
    }

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.Refresh();
}
```

My assumption is I'll have to either Iterate though the [Holiday] Datatable itself, or create another DataTable in the code to store all the associated lines before extracting the details for the displayed table from there.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

I added the rest of my code to show the queries and process. Also to show how I am filling the table, despite outlining how this wasn't where the problem was occurring.

Comment: Your code sounds to be unnecessarily looping on the same data N times. Instead you would create a single select and populate the data in one go. What you are looking is DataTable.Load( cmd.ExecuteReader() ) or adapter.Fill( datatable ). I would prefer using Linq for something like this.

Comment: Cheers for the advice pal, problem is I've written almost all the code for this project in C#, also my boss requested I do it in C#.
My issue was when selecting multiple Values in 1 query is I didn't know how to manage them. Also it Loops because if the employee has more than 1 Holiday it will need to excecute the query+populating chain more than once. The question, if unclear, is how to tell the program to not select a Line it has already selected?

Comment: Josh, I can assure you I have read your original question and the edits :) In my answer, I actually show you why your's doesn't work, did you miss it? You are always selecting (scalarly a single field) the same first row's data using only the PayrollNo as a criteria. When you use ExecuteScalar, even if the query should return multiple rows and columns, you are explicitly asking for the first row's leftmost column data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a slight (incomplete) revision to your code:

```
  string ConnString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\HoliPlanData.accdb;Persist Security Info=False";
  string Query = "SELECT PayrollNo FROM [Employee] WHERE (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) = @Name"; //Will supply selected Employee's PayrollNo

  string getHolidayQuery = @"SELECT StartDate, EndDate, Reason 
     FROM [Holiday] 
     WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo"; // Will select data from Holidays

  string getAbsencesQuery = @"SELECT StartDate, EndDate, Comments 
     FROM [Absences] 
     WHERE PayrollNo = @PayrollNo";

  var holidayData = new DataTable();
  var absenceData = new DataTable();

  using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
  {
    var getPayroll = new OleDbCommand(Query, conn);
    getPayroll.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", LblName.Text);

    var holidaysQuery = new OleDbCommand(getHolidayQuery, conn);
    var absencesQuery = new OleDbCommand(getAbsencesQuery, conn);
    conn.Open();

    int GotPayroll = Convert.ToInt32(getPayroll.ExecuteScalar());   //Uses Query to Get PayrollNo
    holidaysQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayrollNo", GotPayroll);
    absencesQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PayrollNo", GotPayroll);

    holidayData.Load(holidaysQuery.ExecuteReader());
    absenceData.Load(absencesQuery.ExecuteReader());

    conn.Close();
  }

foreach (DataRow row in holidayData.AsEnumerable())
{
    // here you could craft a new data table
    // however there is a discrepancy. 
    // How would the data in Holiday would relate to those
    // in absences. With the relation known, we might have 
    // gotten a single datatable from the database.
    // Probably you should give data samples.


    //    DateTime StartHold = Convert.ToDateTime(GetStart.ExecuteScalar());
    //    DateTime EndHold = Convert.ToDateTime(GetEnd.ExecuteScalar());
    //    string ReasonHold = (GetReason.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();

    // Above lines are sort of saying:
    //    DateTime StartHold = (DateTime)row["StartDate"];
    //    DateTime EndHold = (DateTime)row["EndDate"];
    //    string ReasonHold = (string)row["Reason"];
    // without roundtripping to database per field

  }
//...
```

Basically, what I mean, instead of executing a scalar per field, do a single call to your database. With your scalar approach, there is nothing in query that differentiates "first" row from a second or third one. ie: For payrollNo 5 assume there are 3 holiday entries:

```
5, Jan 22, 2016, Jan 26, 2016
5, Feb 1, 2016, Feb 5, 2016
5, Feb 22, 2016, Feb 26, 2016
```

with your queries, that only use PayrollNo as a criteria, you would always be getting the values from the first row (Jan 22, 2016 for startDate for example).

Getting this data into a local datatable first, provides an iterable structure at least.

Creating a datatable from this data or directly from source, would be easier in one shot, using Linq as I originally said (with Linq it is IQueryable instead of DataTable, but might do with DataTable as well). And Linq is part of C# itself :) Means Language INtegrated Query - IOW query language built into C# itself. Here is a Linq code querying some data from sample Northwind (using IQToolkit from codeplex) - this is all the code you need including Form and DataGridView:

```
void Main()
{
  string path   = @"D:\data\Northwind.accdb";
  string conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+path;

  var provider= new AccessQueryProvider(new OleDbConnection(conStr), 
                    new ImplicitMapping(), QueryPolicy.Default);

  var sampleOrders = provider.GetTable<Order>("Orders")
                  .Where (o => o.OrderDate == new DateTime(1997,1,1));

  Form f = new Form{Height=800,Width=1024};
  DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock=DockStyle.Fill };
  dgv.DataSource = sampleOrders.ToList();

  f.Controls.Add(dgv);
  f.Show();
}

// Entity Class
public class Order {
 public int OrderID { get; set; }
 public string CustomerID { get; set; }
 public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
 public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
 public DateTime? RequiredDate { get; set; }
 public DateTime? ShippedDate { get; set; }
 public int ShipVia { get; set; }
 public decimal? Freight { get; set; }
 public string ShipCity { get; set; }
 public string ShipCountry { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is a brilliant help. Using this method I shall adapt my code and hopefully reach the conclusion I wanted. Thank you :)

Comment: Oh I commented above before seeing this :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

To get the `DataTable` from MS Access Database, use the following sample code snippet:

*Listing* 1. Get `DataTable` from MS Access using `OleDb` object lib

```
private DataTable GetDataTable(string strCN, string strSQL)
{
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection _conn = new OleDbConnection(strCN))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand _command = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                _command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                _command.Connection = _conn;
                _command.CommandText = strSQL;
                _conn.Open();

                using (OleDbDataReader _dr = _command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    DataTable _dt = new DataTable();
                    _dt.Load(_dr);
                    return _dt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

where `strCN` is the connection string and `strSQL` is your SELECT query.You can call this method and pass various SQL queries as a parameter.

Pertinent to your case, it doesn't look like the right SQL SELECT query to do the job. In case you indeed need to obtain the `DataTable` and then bind it to data-aware controls (like `GridView`) then you should use the method provided above. Should you need to get just a scalar value, use the following method in Listing 2.

*Listing 2.* Get scalar value from MS Access using `OleDb` object lib

```
/// <summary>
/// Read DB Read Scalar on SQL command input
/// </summary>
/// <param name="SQL">string</param>
/// <returns>string</returns>
private static string ReadScalar(string ConnString, string SQL)
{
    string _ret;
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection _conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand _command = new OleDbCommand(SQL, _conn))
            {
                _command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                _conn.Open();
                _ret = _command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            }
            return _ret;
        }
    }
    catch { return null; }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks Alex. However this isn't an answer to the question I actually asked.

Comment: It's as if you saw the Title of the question but that's as far as you got.

Comment: This is the direct answer to your question as you put it in title. As it was already mentioned by member @Cetin Bazos, your code is excessively complex - it should be a single query composed in a right way (probably using Group By/aggregate SQL functions and sub-queries), then loading the DataTable and binding it to GridView. That's it. Correct your query and it will work. Best regards,

Comment: Brilliant help. Hopefully sarcasm isn't lost through this text.

Comment: If you read more than the question title you would understand.

Comment: The title should relate to your question, but it looks like you are asking for something different, namely: how to write SQL queries and C# code for your project. Sorry, but SO is not a free code writing service. Please narrow down you question pertinent to the title, then we can help. Best regards,

Comment: Or Actually read what I've written before suggesting your 'help'? The question title provides an overview for an indepth question. If I knew a better way to structure my Queries, OBVIOUSLY I WOULD HAVE. I'm not asking for free code. I'm asking for advice from people who may know how to solve my problem. The way I'm asking is by describing EXACTLY what my problem is. Unfortunately a question title doesn't provide enough space. The question is simple and understandable if you took the time to look at it. Since you obviously didn't, please keep your advice. It's not helpful.

Comment: The only useful comment was how you think I may have used the wrong Query. THANKS A BUNCH! Now which query is wrong? How can I adapt it? Have you managed to infer anything other that what I've written in the question?

Comment: I would suggest to accept the answer and post another question clearly stating the ACTUAL problem, that YOU NEED HELP in composing the right query for the task, and provide the accurate description of that task. Show just essential part of your code directly related to the residual problem (the other part of the question has been already answered here). Best regards,

Comment: Alex, while these are samples for getting DataTables given an SQL string and a connection string, they lack parameters and unnecessarily long. I think one would choose to code a shorter version and possibly one with parameters support.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Thanks for your comments, but I am not going to waste any more time on this stuff. Based on my qualified guess, the entire problem could be solved relatively easy in MS Access DB per se, then the result query could be called from C# to get DataTable using the method in Listing 1. If PO post another question clearly stating the problem, then I will take a look into it and possibly provide a solution. Best regards,

Comment: That is what I thought too :) Except for a slight local processing.

Comment: @Josh, please, he is trying to help. No need to argue, just better explain your needs and get better help.

Comment: @CetinBasoz Thanks again, I appreciate. Have a great day. My best,

Comment: Hey @Josh, watch your mouth! And better learn at least the basics of SQL instead of attacking people who are trying to help.

Comment: @Alex, don't try to help before reading the question. The key point is I'm TRYING to learn. You're attempts of help were completely irrelevant to the answer I was seeking. If I need to say again how sometimes a question cannot be over-viewed in a question title. There's something for you to learn; read the question. (Pretty sure they still teach that in school)

Comment: @Josh You must stop posting such offensive comments and apologize for your utterly unprofessional and abusive behavior! I'm giving you a serious warning - such behavior will not be tolerated.

Comment: @AlexBell . Woah pal calm down. My comments are justified and not aimed to be offensive, more to be constructive, hopefully leading your future answers to be more useful to whomever you've felt like 'helping'.
My sincerest apologies that you have taken my words in an offensive manner, since that was not my intent.

Comment: Maybe remove your answer as it isn't related to the question that was asked?
Edit - Scratch that, I'll accept it as a useful answer, although it wasn't useful to me, other novice programmers could possibly gain something from it.

Comment: @Josh - yours are the most unpleasant comments I have seen on StackOverflow.  I have been a member for quite a few years now and have never seen such a childish response.

Comment: @HughJones Thanks a lot, I really appreciate. Best regards,

Comment: My apologies that you may have taken offence. I understand I have a blunt manner of speech, and however unpleasantly you may have received my words, they were not sent with the intent to upset. Sorry if your feeling have been hurt guys.