# Displaying the data between two datetimepicker,."Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I don't know what's the possible problem for this.

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

Here's my current code:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace NiceyBurgerJunction
{
    public partial class frmSales : Form
{

 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\mariel\Desktop\NiceyBurgerJunction\NiceyBurgerJunctionDB.accdb");

int count;


    public frmSales()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnWeeklySales_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            count = 0;
            DateTime from, to;

            from = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value);
            to = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker2.Value);

            dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
            dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;

            con.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ProdName,SubTotal,OrderDate from EmployeeSale WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '" + from.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' AND '" + to.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "' ";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            if (count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No records found!");
            }

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" ERROR " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

My database design is in correct format for "OrderDate", the properties for this is Date/Time...

Comment: Why don't you share the error message in text form? And what triggers the error?

Comment: I already attach the image for the error sir.. in "enter image description here"..

Comment: That's the point: don't share an image of your error.

Comment: am sorry sir...

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?  Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35867698/how-to-populate-datatable-correctly-using-oledb-queries   it should help.

Comment: If there is an error with the SQL query, have you tried dumping the error and running it using some database tool like a windows client for your server?

Comment: There is edit button, so instead of saying you're sorry, fix the issue. Also, learn how to take screenshots, if you need to take one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the format of the date you pass to your SQL-statement is not correct.
I guess it should be YYYY-MM-DD rather than MM/DD/YYYY.
Also consider using a statement with parameters. This way you can just pass the DateTime that you have and the driver will take care of formatting things. You can just use the `DbCommand.Paramerers.Add` API for that and then reference the parameters as `@from` and `@to` for instance.

Read up on using parameters here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Also there are several flaws in your code (like executing the command once with `ExecuteNonQuery`, setting the format of the datetime-pickers after you read their value for no reason...).

cheers